# one-to-many relationship with join table: relation not being persisted

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using hibernate JPA annotations, and as for repositories I'm using Spring JPA

i have the following two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "idn_organization")
@Audited
public class Organization extends UuidBasedEntity {
    @Column(name = "full_name", length = 64, nullable = false)
    private String fullName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "idn_organization_address",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    )
    private Set<Address> addresses;

    @Column(name = "phone_number", length = 12, nullable = true)
    private String phoneNo;

    @Column(name = "registered_date", nullable = true)
    private Date registeredDate;

    @Column(name = "social_security", length = 9, nullable = true)
    private String socialSecurity;

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public Set<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses != null ? addresses : new HashSet<Address>();
    }

    public void setAddresses(Set<Address> addresses) {
        if (this.addresses == null)
            this.addresses = new HashSet<>();

        this.addresses.clear();

        if (addresses != null)
            this.addresses.addAll(addresses);
    }
```

And:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cmn_address")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Audited
public class Address extends AutoIdBasedEntity {

    @Valid
    @NotNull(message = "{address.type.notNull}")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_code")
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_address_address_type")
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    private AddressType type;

    @NotNull(message = "{address.line1.notNull}")
    @Column(name = "address_line_1", length = 256, nullable = true)
    private String addressLine1;

    @Column(name = "address_line_2", length = 128, nullable = true)
    private String addressLine2;

    @Column(name = "address_line_3", length = 128, nullable = true)
    private String addressLine3;

    @Valid
    @NotNull(message = "{address.town.notNull}")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    private Town city;

    @NotNull(message = "{address.state.notNull}")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 2, message = "{address.state.notEmpty}")
    @Column(name = "state_code")
    private String state;

    //@NotNull(message = "{address.zip.notNull}")
    // TODO Not all DTOP Results match
    // @Pattern(regexp = "\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?", message = "{address.zip.notValid}")
    @Column(name = "postal_code", length = 32, nullable = true)
    private String postalCode;

    @Valid
    @NotNull(message = "{address.country.notNull}")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_code")
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    private Country country;
```

As mentioned my repository is:

```
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organization, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Organization> {
}
```

The problem I'm having is specifically with the method save in my service:

```
@Service("identityService")
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class IdentityServiceImpl implements IdentityService {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IdentityServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private OrganizationRepository organizationRepository;

    @Override
    public void persistOrganization(Organization organization) {
        organizationRepository.save(organization);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Organization [" +
                    organization.getUuid() + " - " +
                    organization.getFullName() + "] created or updated.");
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I call my save method the organization is persisted and so is the address in their respective tables... but the join table entry is not! Therefore, I obtain a new organization, a new address, but there's no link between them. So what am I doing wrong here? It obviously also happens when I try to edit the organization somehow.

Comment: Here is your answer: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Getters_and_Setters.
 BTW `FetchType.EAGER` is the default behaviour so you don't need to explicitly specify it. I suggest you to use `FetchType.LAZY` instead

Comment: umm, keep in mind that i have no back-reference to `Organization` under `Address` so it is uni-directional. I added an `addAddress` method, and the problem still occurs. Also I'm using a `joinTable`, not a `joinColumn`.

Comment: oh it is a `joinTable` so it is `ManyToMany` relationship and it is always bidirectional. 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Bi-directional_Many_to_Many

Comment: its a oneToMany relation with a join table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my service as I had the annotation:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

and because I was managing transactions through web flow, they never commited. So I added `@Transactional` to the persist methods and that fixed it. You can also just remove the `readOnly = true` part, but I didn't because there were fetch methods that I didn't want to be exposed.